# get difference between two dates in $project

Tags: json, mongodb, aggregation-framework, projection

Trying to project the date difference between two dates, but I am getting error -

> Invalid $project :: caused by :: Unknown expression $dateDiff

```
db.books.aggregate([{
$project:{
  Date_diff: 
    {$dateDiff:{
      start_dt:'$borrowers_list.borrowed_dt',
      endDate:'$borrowers_list.return_dt',
      unit: "day"
    }
  }
}
}])
```

The json document structure is like this -

```
_id:6188a5283543f7cc2f77c73f
branch_id:1
    borrowers_list:Object    
        0:Object
            borrowed_dt:2021-08-15T06:00:00.000+00:00
            card_no:"ID000067"
            return_dt:2021-08-25T06:00:00.000+00:00
```

I have no idea why the error is unknown expression $dateDiff, as my syntax is correct. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Does your `borrowers_list` is an object or array?

Comment: check your mongodb version also, you need mongodb 5 for datefiff

Comment: @Takis_, my version is 4.4. I think that is the problem.

Comment: if you cant use mongodb 5, you can use subtract to get the dates difference in milliseconds and then divide to get the days with    `24*60*60 * 1000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your provided JSON document, the document should be as below (correct me if it is incorrect):

```
  {
    _id: ObjectId("6188a5283543f7cc2f77c73f"),
    branch_id: 1,
    borrowers_list: {
      0: {
        borrowed_dt: ISODate("2021-08-15T06:00:00.000+00:00"),
        card_no: "ID000067",
        return_dt: ISODate("2021-08-25T06:00:00.000+00:00")
      }
    }
  }
]
```

There is no `start_dt` in [`$dateFiff`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateDiff/) field, it is `startDate`.

> Query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      Date_diff: {
        $dateDiff: {
          startDate: "$borrowers_list.0.borrowed_dt",
          endDate: "$borrowers_list.0.return_dt",
          unit: "day"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

***Note: Above query will perform the `$dateDiff` for the first document in `borrowers_list`.***

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NjQnX3T_JVM)

---

In case you need to iterate each document (with key-value pair) in `borrowers_list` to perform `$dateDiff`.

1. `$set` - Convert from object to array (via `$objectToArray`) for `borrowers_list` to new field `borrowers`.
2. `$set` - Iterate each document in `borrowers` array (1) and perform `$dateDiff`.
3. `$project` - Decorate the output document, convert `Date_diff` from array to object (via `$objectToArray`).

> Query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      borrowers: {
        "$objectToArray": "$borrowers_list"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      Date_diff: {
        $map: {
          input: "$borrowers",
          as: "b",
          in: {
            k: "$$b.k",
            v: {
              $dateDiff: {
                startDate: "$$b.v.borrowed_dt",
                endDate: "$$b.v.return_dt",
                unit: "day"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      Date_diff: {
        "$arrayToObject": "$Date_diff"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Iterate document with key-value pair)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OSXdWYFgAtD)

Comment: My version is 4.4, so I just realized that dateDiff will not work for me. However, I am still able to find your answer useful. Thanks.